# How to get the level of a node in a generic tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, nodes, tree-traversal

Given a generic tree implemented as a root node with a list of sons, which sons are nodes and again each node has a list of its sons.

```
   __A__ 
  /  |  \
 B   C   D
 |  / \
 E  F  G
```

The node `A` has a list of its sons: `B, C, D`

`B, C, D` also have a list of their sons: `B --> E` ; `C --> F, G` ; `D --> null` ;

I will explain my idea of the algorithm, you can fix it or give me another completely new idea.

```
public Integer level(T dato) {...}
```

Traverse the tree adding to the queue each node of the tree or adding a "null" if the last node added is the last node of the level. Null is an identifier in the queue to know where the level has ended. 
My problem is that I don't know exactly where to put the identifier after the first time. 
Here is some of the code:

```
    public Integer level(T data){
    int inclu= this.include(data);
    if (inclu==-1) {        // if the tree doesn't include the data
        return -1;
    } else {               
        return inclu;       // returns the level
    }
}

public Integer include( T data ) {  // returns the level where the data is
    Integer inclu = -1;     // -1 if the data is not included
    if (this.getDataRoot()==data){
        return 0;       //  The root of the tree has the data
    }
    else {
        LinkedList<GenericNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<GenericNode<T>>();

        GenericNode<T> tree = new GenericNode<T>();

        int level=1;
        queue.addAtBeginning(this.getRoot());
        queue.addAtBeginning(null);

        while (queue.size()>0 && inclu==-1) {

            if(queue.element(queue.size())!=null) {                         // if it is not the end of the level then dequeue

                tree.setData(queue.element(queue.size()).getData());        //queue.element(position) returns the element in that position
                tree.setListOfSons(queue.element(queue.size()).getSons());

                if (tree.getSons()!=null) {     // if the tree has sons
                    int i=1;
                    while(i<=tree.getSons().size() && inclu==-1) {
                        queue.addAtBeginning(tree.getSons().element(i));
                        if (tree.getSons().element(i).getData()==data)      // if I found the data I'm looking for
                            inclu=level;
                        i++;                                                // counter
                    }   
                }       
            } else {    // if it is the end of the level (means the queue gave me a null)
                level++;    
            }

            queue.delete(queue.size());         //ending the dequeue process

        } //end while
    } // end main else

    return inclu;       //returns the summation of the levels or 0 if it was found at the root of the tree or -1 if the data was not found
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm should be a breadth-first-search. If you google that, you should find a good explanation. Probably on wikipedia :)

Comment: Is is approach how you would do it, without a computer? Imagine a tree of this structure being given to you, printed out or something. The tree is too big for you to just glance and see that a given item is on such-and-such level. How would you go about figuring out its level? If you think about it that way, chances are you'll find a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a class that returns the level of target node in specific tree.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.List;

public class TreeLevel {

public static class Node {
    public Node(String data) { this.data = data ; };
        public String data;
        public List<Node> childs = new LinkedList<Node>();
    }

public static Integer level(Node tree, Node target){
    return level(tree, target, 0);
}

private static Integer level(Node tree, Node target, int currentLevel) {
    Integer returnLevel = -1;        
    if(tree.data.equals(target.data)) {
        returnLevel = currentLevel;
    } else {
        for(Node child : tree.childs) {
            if((returnLevel = level(child, target, currentLevel + 1)) != -1){
                break;
            }                
        }
    }
    return returnLevel;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node a = new Node("A");
    Node b = new Node("B");        
    Node c = new Node("C");
    Node d = new Node("D");        
    Node e = new Node("E");
    Node f = new Node("F");
    Node g = new Node("G");

    // childs of a:
    a.childs.add(b);
    a.childs.add(c);
    a.childs.add(d);

    // childs of b:
    b.childs.add(e);

    // childs of c:
    c.childs.add(f);
    c.childs.add(g);

    // childs of d:
    // d.childs = null or simply d.childs.length() is 0 
    Node target = new Node("G");
    Integer level = level(a, target);
    System.out.println("level [" + level + "]");


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I can give you a simple code for this question. You can change the it according to your code.

```
public Integer include( T data ) {  // returns the level where the data is
    Integer inclu = -1;     // -1 if the data is not included
    if (this.getDataRoot() == data){
        return 0;       //  The root of the tree has the data
    }

    return level(this.getRoot(), data, 1);
}

//Find data in a tree whose root is Node
//If not found, return -1
public int level(T node, T data, int level) {

    if (!node.hasChildren()) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (T child : node.getChildren()) {
        if (child.getData == data) {
             return level; //Aha!!! found it
        } else {
             int l = level(child, data, level + 1); /// find in this sub-tree
             if (l != -1) {
                 return l;
             }
        }
    }
    return -1;  /// Not found in this sub-tree.
}


P.S : == is used to compare, which is not good. .equals() should be used.
```